# Is it safe to assume the API will be at api.<DOMAIN>?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm writing an application that will eventually allow you to use it for any StackExchange site. Thus, I'm allowing users to input the domains of the sites they want to use (e.g. `stackoverflow.com`). I'm not sure whether it's safe to assume the API will always be at `api.<DOMAIN>` (and on all StackExchange sites) -- will there be other subdomains? E.g. `ws.<DOMAIN>` (for web service).

Basically, I don't know whether I should ask the user for `stackoverflow.com` and prepend `api.` myself or ask for the full `api.stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: I was going to ask this myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Before the API leaves beta there will be a mechanism for discovering API end points.  Don't make any hard assumptions about API locations (beyond the necessary hardcoding at this time).

Comment: Once we have discovered the endpoint, is it safe to keep it forever, or should we be prepared to rediscover it later?

Comment: @Farseeker - you will be able to cache aggressively, but forever is a long time.  Expect more details when such a method is available.