# Will URLs always follow this pattern?

Tags: feature-request, api, url-syntax

Many of the API endpoints return urls, such as `/questions/{id}` (which returns urls for `question_timeline_url`, `question_comments_url`, etc).  However, the URL returned is a relative URL, like `/questions/{id}/timeline`.

However, this URL is not relative to the API url.  It's relative to a URL that we (potentially) don't know.  Theoretically we could compute the base URL by removing the "api." subdomain, but I'm hesitant to hard-code this assumption into [my framework](https://stackapps.com/questions/346).

So my question is:

Can I always assume that removing the "api." subdomain will result in the base url of the site?  I understand that this is currently true for stackoverflow.com, meta.stackoverflow.com, etc, but will this always be true for every future StackExchange site?

**edit** S.Mark has pointed out that the API subdomain can't be relied upon.  In which case:

Can we get the absolute URL instead?

**edit #2** Kevin's comment reminded me that the URLs returned with the results aren't necessarily user-visible.  They're API URLs.  Doh!

Comment: The returned urls **are** relative to the API url.  They're effectively pointers to related methods.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the following question,

> Can I always assume that removing the
>   "api." subdomain will result in the
>   base url of the site?

No, According to Kevin [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/545/is-it-safe-to-assume-the-api-will-be-at-api-domain)

Comment: +1 thanks for reminding me of that question (which I've even up-voted!).  In this case, my feature-request stands. :)

Comment: @Dave Delong, How about `base_url` in stats page, instead of everything as Absolute URL?

Comment: Mark that could work, I suppose.  It'd be nice to have it as part of the response, since I can't guarantee that the `stats` endpoint will have been invoked yet.  I could invoke it myself automatically, I suppose... I'll have to think about that and see if any official response comes.